# Remapping Artist Shortcut Remote in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux, xorg, keyboard-layout

I am using the XP Pen Shortcut Remote that comes with the Deco Pro tablet, it has a dial and 10 keys. Each key (and the dial) is mapped to a keyboard stroke by default. For example pressing the top left key sends a Ctrl+O key stroke.

Using `sudo evtest` you can see its two distinct keycodes for a single button press:

```
Event: time 1711486381.107788, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1711486381.107788, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1711486381.107788, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70012
Event: time 1711486381.107788, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 24 (KEY_O), value 1
Event: time 1711486381.107788, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
^OEvent: time 1711486381.197735, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1711486381.197735, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1711486381.197735, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70012
Event: time 1711486381.197735, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 24 (KEY_O), value 0
Event: time 1711486381.197735, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

So I am not really sure how to remap this specific button (and others like it). Since methods like xkb, kmonad and even evdev remapping for what I understand works off of the unique keycodes sent by a single button press.

XP-Pen has a driver that works with Linux on their website that allows you to remap these buttons but only when the driver is running, it doesnt allow you to save those configurations into the keyboard remote itself.

I was wondering if its possible to bypass this since I would like to not have to resort to their proprietary software. Is there somehow a way to know which button is being clicked and remapping it?